# vfork+execve strange when using syscall

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

If you execute the code below you'll see execve returns a process id and parent never executes. I tried looking for documentation but I either can't find it or can't understand it. clone talks about vfork (CLONE_VFORK) and says the below but the parent never seems to execute. If you uncomment the non sys call vfork or use the syscall fork it'll work as expected

> the execution of the calling process is suspended until the child releases its virtual memory resources via a call to execve(2) or _exit(2) (as with vfork(2)).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //int a = vfork();
    //int a = syscall(__NR_fork);
    int a = syscall(__NR_vfork);
    if (a) {
        write(2, "parent\n", 7);
    } else {
        char*args[] = {"/usr/bin/true", (char*)0};
        int res = execve(args[0], args, &argv[2]);
        char buf[256];
        sprintf(buf, "child got %d\n", res);
        write(2, buf, strlen(buf));
    }
    write(2, "Done\nChild\n", a?5:11);
}
```

Comment: `execve()` doesn't return if it's successful. So if it returns you should use `perror()` to print the reason. I suspect the problem is with `&argv[2]`. You're supposed to pass a pointer to the environment array there. If you don't have an environment array, use `execv()` instead of `execve()`.

Comment: If `execve()` fails, the parent stays suspended until the child exits.

Comment: Just not using `vfork()` is the way to go, really.

Comment: What is "child reset"?

Comment: `execve()` is not a raw syscall. It does update `errno`.

Comment: From [man execve](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#RETURN_VALUE): **On success, execve() does not return, on error -1 is returned,
       and errno is set to indicate the error.**

Comment: vfork is weird because of the way the child and parent share resources. If you change to `__NR_fork` it all works fine. You shouldn't do anything in the child process after `execve()`.

Comment: Really, you should just not use `vfork()` at all. It was created to solve a problem that existed in the slow hardware of the 1970's. It's no longer needed.

Comment: I tried compiling your code on my Mac but it doesn't have `<syscall.h>`. Just use `fork()`.

Comment: You also had it tagged `assembler` but there's no asseembly code.

Comment: @Barmar system calls are commonly written in assembly. I wasn't using libc system call, so I write my implementation using assembly

Comment: Use of `vfork` [via libc function or direct syscall] is problematic. Your code has _undefined behavior_ (per the spec). This means it _may_ work on one system/implementation or fail/crash on another. Andrew's answer explains [in detail] why.

Comment: `strace -f ./a.out` shows that the parent is still executing, and in fact is the process that makes the `write(2, "Done\nChild\n", 11)` system call.  It's the child process that's no longer executing this code (after successful `execve`).  I compiled with `gcc` 12.2 without optimization on Arch GNU/Linux.  No idea what compiler you might have used, un-optimized GCC is just a guess.

Comment: @Barmar refer to peters answer to why I tagged assembly and why I didn't want you, andrew  (the other answer) or C people to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious what exactly did happen.  I used `strace -f ./a.out` to see output like this, showing that it's the parent making a `write(2, "Done\nChild\n", 11)` system call.   (lower-numbered PID, and not the new PID strace reports attaching to after vfork)

```
...
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7f7e48c59000, 193483)          = 0
vfork(strace: Process 515667 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 515667] execve("/usr/bin/true", ["/usr/bin/true"], 0x7ffc4447ce18 /* 60 vars */ <unfinished ...>
[pid 515666] <... vfork resumed>)       = 515667
[pid 515666] write(2, "child got 515667\n", 17child got 515667
) = 17
[pid 515667] <... execve resumed>)      = 0
[pid 515666] write(2, "Done\nChild\n", 11Done
Child
) = 11
[pid 515667] brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 515666] exit_group(0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 515667] <... brk resumed>)         = 0x5603b644c000
[pid 515666] <... exit_group resumed>)  = ?
[pid 515667] arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffc878f2720) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
[pid 515666] +++ exited with 0 +++
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
... the parent has exited by now, leaving just the child running the dynamic linker for /usr/bin/true
```

This is terminal output mixed with strace output; I could have used `strace -f -o vfork.trace ./a.out` to capture the log separately, or `./a.out &>/dev/null`.

#### The child overwrites the parent's return address, to the `execve` call site

The actual behaviour of this C code with undefined behaviour happened to be the same with `gcc` (-O0 by default), `gcc -O3`, and `clang -O3`.  So for asm that was easier to single-step with GDB, I built it with `gcc -O3 -fno-plt` on my Arch GNU/Linux system (GCC12.2 in case it matters).  `-fno-plt` means that dynamic linking isn't "lazy", so we can step into library functions.

It was also handy to look at the compiler's asm source with symbolic names (https://godbolt.org/z/j6ME6rWaa).

After `vfork`, GDB detaches the child and lets it run, so you're still single-stepping the parent.

**The parent's return from the glibc `syscall()` wrapper function is *not* to the `test eax,eax` instruction after `call syscall`, it's to the instruction after a different `call`** It seems that after the child returns from `vfork`, it ends up overwriting the return address on the stack before the parent has a chance to run.  That makes sense; the compiler-generated asm for `main` doesn't adjust RSP after function entry, so any other `call` would push a return address to the same place, overwriting the return address in the other process.

The glibc wrapper for `vfork` avoids this by popping the return address around the `syscall` and pushing it right after, to make it work under the conditions where POSIX and the Linux man page says it should. (Which don't include the way you're using it, but even in a safe usage, `call execve` before the parent can `ret` from a wrapper function would be a problem.)  The glibc wrapper's correctness also relies on the kernel semantics of not running the parent until after the child has exited or execve'd, see a later section below; if looking at just the user-space asm, you'd think there'd be a possible race condition and that it might only *usually* work.

The actual place it returned to was a RIP-relative LEA following a `call`, not a `test eax,eax`.  That was the lightbulb moment, the clue that a return address would have been overwritten.  That LEA is setting up args for `sprintf`; the preceding call was `call execve`.

That makes sense; `execve` is the last thing the child did since it only returns on error; on success it replaces the process with a fresh address space that's no longer shared with the parent.

After the child returned from `syscall(__NR_vfork)`,it branched and called `execve`, pushing that return address, overwriting the parent's return address from `call syscall` because they share an address-space including the stack.

**That leaves just the parent, executing from the return path of `execve()`, which in a non-buggy (or non-hacky) program would only be reachable on error.**

So it does the sprintf.  It prints `child got 515667` because that PID was the value in EAX as the parent was returning from `vfork` (to this block of code which takes `res` from the EAX return value of this other call site.)

As for how it manages to pick `11` instead of `5` as the length for the `write` system call, the details probably differ in debug vs. optimized builds.  In an optimized build, different branches of the `if(a)` leave a different number in a register which the call to `write()` uses.

In a debug build, only the child returned to the `vfork` call site and stored an `a` value to the stack.

---

Shenanigans like this are why nobody uses `vfork` anymore; a couple copy-on-write page-faults are cheap enough that it's not worth playing with fire.

It's also why the rules on how you're allowed to use `vfork` are *very* restrictive; you'd better have your args for `execve` already constructed *before* you call `vfork`, so the very next thing can be a `call execve`.

---

#### `syscall(__NR_vfork)` isn't safe; it needs special handling

Single-stepping into the glibc wrapper (`stepi` aka `si` in GDB, in `layout asm` TUI mode), we can see its asm.

```
│    0x7ffff7e7d830 <vfork>          endbr64
│    0x7ffff7e7d834 <vfork+4>        pop    rdi
│    0x7ffff7e7d835 <vfork+5>        mov    eax,0x3a
│    0x7ffff7e7d83a <vfork+10>       syscall
│    0x7ffff7e7d83c <vfork+12>       push   rdi
│  > 0x7ffff7e7d83d <vfork+13>       cmp    eax,0xfffff001     # EAX >= -ERRNO_MAX
│    0x7ffff7e7d842 <vfork+18>       jae    0x7ffff7e7d858 <vfork+40>                                                                                                                                                                
               # else no-error return path.
│    0x7ffff7e7d844 <vfork+20>       xor    esi,esi
│    0x7ffff7e7d846 <vfork+22>       rdsspq rsi
│    0x7ffff7e7d84b <vfork+27>       test   rsi,rsi   # if shadow stack not in use
│    0x7ffff7e7d84e <vfork+30>       je     0x7ffff7e7d857 <vfork+39>
│    0x7ffff7e7d850 <vfork+32>       test   eax,eax   # in parent, normal return
│    0x7ffff7e7d852 <vfork+34>       jne    0x7ffff7e7d857 <vfork+39>
│    0x7ffff7e7d854 <vfork+36>       pop    rdi         # pop real return address
│    0x7ffff7e7d855 <vfork+37>       jmp    rdi         # and manually return to the correct address from the shadow stack?

     # no shadow-stack path of execution, return normally.
│    0x7ffff7e7d857 <vfork+39>       ret

  # error handling, set errno and return -1
│    0x7ffff7e7d858 <vfork+40>       mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x105509]        # 0x7ffff7f82d68
│    0x7ffff7e7d85f <vfork+47>       neg    eax
│    0x7ffff7e7d861 <vfork+49>       mov    DWORD PTR fs:[rcx],eax
│    0x7ffff7e7d864 <vfork+52>       or     rax,0xffffffffffffffff   # code-size optimization for mov rax,-1   (really rarely executed for most system calls)
│    0x7ffff7e7d868 <vfork+56>       ret
```

`rdsspq` reads the "shadow stack" pointer, in case the caller was using CET, Control-flow Enforcement Technology.  I'm not familiar with CET, so my comments on that part are guesswork based on what this function probably needs to do, and how it's using these instructions.

I should have just looked at the [hand-written glibc source](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/vfork.S.html) which has comments, `glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/vfork.S`; updated with some from there.

It seems like there could still be a race with the child, like if our `push rdi` runs before the child returns and calls `execve`.  Under normal scheduling conditions, though, the child does run first.

But no, there's special logic to handle that:

> https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html
>
> `vfork()` differs from `fork(2)` in that **the calling thread is
> suspended until the child terminates** (either normally, by calling
> _exit(2), or abnormally, after delivery of a fatal signal), **or it
> makes a call to `execve(2)`**.  Until that point, the child shares
> all memory with its parent, including the stack.  The child must
> not return from the current function or call exit(3) (which would
> have the effect of calling exit handlers established by the
> parent process and flushing the parent's stdio(3) buffers), but
> may call _exit(2).

---

As you mentioned in comments, if you wanted to use this for concurrency / threading, use `pthread_create(3)` to start threads, not `vfork()`!  Or the same raw system call it uses, `clone(CLONE_THREAD)`.  (Note that the glibc wrapper for `clone` uses the new thread's stack memory to store a code pointer to be called; the kernel API/ABI doesn't have a code-pointer arg; see the [C library / kernel differences](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html#NOTES) part of the man page, and maybe the glibc ource code for `clone()`.)

These days, `vfork` is implemented inside the kernel as `clone( flags=CLONE_VM | CLONE_VFORK | SIGCHLD )`.

Comment: Bingo, this is why I originally tagged the question as assembly. I ended up rewriting the C code (without the write and such) and was completely confused why the assembly code seemed to have both parent and child return from the first system call and in the C code the parent returns from the second call. After writing inline assembly into C I realized that syscall isn't actually inlined and that returning from a function is undefined, which made me more annoyed because why even have a C implementation if it's completely illegal. I also saw C use vfork in strace

Comment: I didn't end up figuring out why the parent continue from execve, That all makes sense. The broken code happened to work when I moved it into my main code (to see how badly it would blow up). It didn't and I was suspicious. I saw a 200ms improvement over fork so I rewrote the code to use clone (which kept the 200ms improvement).. I feel better knowing WHY the c code failed as miserably as it did and what glibc did to insert its magic

Comment: Yes there's a special condition. It's mentioned in `man vfork` but `man clone` is better. There's the `CLONE_VFORK` flag which says "If CLONE_VFORK is set, the execution of the calling is suspended until the child releases its virtual resources via a call to execve(2) or _exit(2) (as vfork(2))." So you're seeing correct code, no races there. I was planning to reuse the vfork (before realizing how bad/special all this is) for multi threaded processes. I'm using clone now instead.

Comment: @Henry: re: your first comment about why even have a C function for `vfork`: did you read the last section of my answer which explains how glibc works around the problem?  The `vfork()` function in glibc saves the return address before `syscall`, restoring it right after returning from the kernel so things are well-defined (thanks to the CLONE_VFORK semantics of suspending the parent which you found).  The problem is invoking it manually via `syscall(__NR_vfork)`.

Comment: And yeah, definitely use `clone` for starting threads, they can start with their own stack, with RSP pointing somewhere sensible.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I did but the 5mins was up so I couldn't clarify that it was my reaction when I initially noticed that syscall wasn't a macro/inlined and it'd break/undefined when I use that instead of the glibc version. Their solution is clever. I never thought about using a register to preserve a value across a syscall. I mostly use assembly to toy around with my own runtime and I'm not sure if I'll go down the OS rabbithole

Comment: I tend to read your answer, reply, reread, then after coding/doing things for an hour reread the answer because I tend to not understand every word until the 3rd (or sometimes 5th) readthrough. Like the use an 64bit int to do a 16bit compare instead of SIMD exercise the other week. That one blew my mind

Comment: I noticed fork with threads copied and ran threads so threads seemed to be racing with itself. I'm assuming (more like hoping) if I create threads with clone doing a clone version of vfork (`CLONE_VM | CLONE_VFORK | SIGCHLD`) won't have any funny business with my threads. I don't think it needs to suspend my thread execution (which would be fine) but I hope these flags don't make a copy. I have enough worker threads and don't need any more memory contention or race conditions

Comment: Each thread needs its own stack if you want them to be running simultaneously.  `CLONE_VM | CLONE_VFORK` is not very usable.  Use `CLONE_THREAD` instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple instances of undefined behavior in the code.

You are invoking undefined behavior by making calls such as `sprintf()` and `write()` after `execve()` fails.  [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/vfork.html):

> ... the behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit()` or one of the exec family of functions.

Even simply returning from `main()` after `vfork()` invokes undefined behavior.

@Barmar summed it up best: "you should just not use `vfork()` at all"

This code also invokes undefined behavior:

```
    char*args[] = {"/usr/bin/true", (char*)0};
    int res = execve(args[0], args, &argv[2]);
```

`argv[2]` doesn't exist, so passing its address to `execve()` invokes undefined behavior.  Note that taking the address of `argv[2]` does not in itself invoke undefined behavior - an address one past the actual end of an array does exist.  But it can't be safely derferenced, which `execve()` will do.

[`execve()` expects a pointer to an array of environment pointers as its third argument](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/execve.html#tag_03_130_06_05):

> **Using execve()**
>
> The following example passes arguments to the ls command in the cmd
> array, and specifies the environment for the new process image using
> the env argument.
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
>
> int ret;
> char *cmd[] = { "ls", "-l", (char *)0 };
> char *env[] = { "HOME=/usr/home", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0 };
> ...
> ret = execve ("/bin/ls", cmd, env);
> ```

Comment: In practice the environment array is typically right after the argv array, so `&argv[2]` will accidentally generate the correct pointer. Undefined behavior will sometimes do what you wanted, but you shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: @Henry You are invoking undefined behavior.  "Appears to work properly" is one possible result.  Failing intermittently is another.

Comment: @Henry If you'd tagged it assembly I might have replaced it with C, since the code is written in C. I don't see how this is about the x86 syscall instruction, it's about how the Linux `vfork` and `execve` system calls work, which you invokved using C. Nothing about assembly at all.

Comment: @Henry *The question is about linux x86-64 syscall not the c standards.*  No, it's about the behavior of `vfork()`.  When you use `vfork()`, both the parent and child processes share the same address space.  When you do the things the POSIX (not C) standard says are undefined behavior in the child process, **you BREAK the parent process** because you modify the parent's memory. It doesn't matter whether `vfork()` was called via the standard `vfork()` function or your own direct assembly system call. And once you get to undefined behavior, no one needs to run your code at all to prove anything.

Comment: @Henry Now you're taking incomplete quotes from [Linux man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) while ignoring other parts: "The child must not return from the current function or call exit(3)" and "The child process should take care not to modify the memory in unintended ways".  Note that **not one word** of the Linux man page contradicts the POSIX standard - your code invokes undefined behavior.  Full stop.  Linux did not break userspace here - **YOU** did by having the kernel `vfork()` your process and then ignoring the restrictions that puts on the child process.

Comment: @Henry *Because I can show you right now that a system call to exit WILL RETURN A PROCESS ID.*  Utterly **IRRELEVANT**.  You break the rules for `vfork()`.  Game over.  If you can't handle the fact that invoking undefined behavior means your code will have **meaningless** unpredictable results that no one is going to **volunteer** to bother trying to reproduce  **because there is NO "solution" for undefined behavior**, you're in over your head trying to write C code.  Or assembler.   And you certainly have no right or even reason to complain about it.

Comment: Sigh. It's stupid SO lets people change tags. I guess I needed to explicitly say I can make exit return a value in an example that's well defined. I guess it's too much to say try moving args to above vfork and delete the dead code under execve. It took less time for me to figure what was going on then the time it took me to read your and Barmar comments. Between you two and the random people upvoting his nonsensical answers I'm extremely irritated. At least I can now articulate what's going on in the example and how to correct it

Comment: @Henry *I needed to explicitly say I can make exit return a value in an example that's well defined*  Again - **irrelevant**.  You corrupted the parent process when you broke the rules for `vfork()` in the child process.  Whatever makes it "work" can change with the next new moon.  You appear to be well on your way to creating systems with nine 5's of reliability.

Comment: Its bold of you to claim that when you haven't seen my assembly code. I'm pretty happy that I'll never use software that you and Barmar have written. I'm pretty sad that I'll be forced to use software modified by people who write code the same quality as the rest of this site

Comment: @Henry You need to step back and think.  Do you even **know** what "undefined behavior" means?  If you don't, you **seriously** need to stop thinking you know everything because, frankly, right now you're just smart enough to be dangerous to C and assembly code.  Until you remove the undefined behavior in your code, how it acts when you change things is **irrelevant**.  A simple change to an environment variable, or a particular address layout from ASLR could make code you falsely believe to "work" blow up.  And you can **never** know when it might happen.  And you can **never** prevent it.

Comment: (cont) But hey, who am I to keep you from writing code to low standards.

Comment: @Henry: Your question didn't show the assembly generated by the compiler you used, or the build command(s) and compiler version, or the kernel version you tested on.  So there was not enough info available for people to write an asm answer that looked at the detailed reasons for getting exactly *this* symptom from the undefined behaviour from using `vfork` incorrectly (initializing a local `char *args[]` array after vfork, so in a debug build that probably stores to the stack.)  If you'd wanted an asm answer, you need to give more info and do more than just tag [assembly].

Comment: @Henry: ... *when you haven't seen my assembly code*.  Nobody has, because your question wasn't a [mcve] of your hand-written `syscall` wrapper and the compiler-generated asm you're asking about.  Sorry we couldn't read your mind. >.<

Comment: @Henry: I was curious what exactly did happen; seems that after the child returns from `vfork`, it ends up overwriting the return address on the stack before the parent runs.  (I single-stepped in GDB, and the `call syscall` returned to a different place than it was executed from.  Not to the `test eax,eax` after that `call` (in a `gcc -O3 -fno-plt` build), but to the instruction after the `call execve` call site.  So that's how that code manages to get executed, despite execve not returning!)

Comment: @AndrewHenle see peters answer and my comments. I guess my nine 5's are actually five 9's

Comment: @Henry *I guess my nine 5's are actually five 9's*  And with that you have demonstrated your complete lack of understanding of what undefined behavior means.  What part of "to make it *usually* work" even starts to pretend to imply any acceptable level of reliability?  The fact you entirely missed that is telling.  Nine 5s remains your standard.